# Selectively disabling plugins from loading in Wordpress admin area

Tags: performance, wordpress, plugins, admin

Does anybody know how to disable certain plugins from loading in the back-end/admin area of Wordpress?

Currently I'm running a site that has many plugins mainly geared towards front-end manipulation yet when I access pages in the backend (ie. /wp-admin/edit.php) **all** CSS, JS and plugin files are being loaded for plugins that are not required there, thus increasing the load-time and responsiveness of the admin area.

I'm looking for a solution, either plugin based for code that can selectively load admin only plugins, ideally without having to hack the core files.

I'm using wordpress 3.5.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Checkout [Plugin Organizer](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/plugin-organizer/). I haven't used it but according to it's description, you can "Selectively disable plugins by any post type or wordpress managed URL". I would guess that you could disable certain plugins from running on urls that contain `/wp-admin/`.

You can also modify the plugins themselves. It depends how they are written, but you can find where they are enqueuing the css and js files and wrap those in an `is_admin()` statement like this:

```
// Make sure we aren't in the admin area
if ( !is_admin() ) {
    wp_enqueue_script('plugin-script');
    wp_enqueue_style('plugin-style');
}
```

That will ensure that the scripts/styles are only loaded on the front end.

Another possibility is to find all of the css and script files that are being loaded via plugins and deregister them in your `functions.php` file. This will require you to poke around the plugins a bit to find the handles of all the files, but it should work well. This would deregister some of the default stuff enqueued in the admin area, so you can see what I mean.

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'remove_admin_styles' );

function remove_admin_styles() {
    wp_deregister_style(
        'wp-admin',
        'ie',
        'colors',
        'colors-fresh',
        'colors-classic',
        'media',
        'install',
        'thickbox'
    );
}
```

As you said, you don't want to mess with core files, but if you absolutely need to you can implement the solution described in [this article](http://betterwp.net/15-wordpress-selective-plugin-loading/). As I'm sure you know, it's not a good idea to alter WordPress core files unless you absolutely have to. Just keep in mind that the changes will be wiped out if you upgrade WordPress in the future.

Comment: I'd recommend Plugin Organizer. It's a little confusing to setup and the documentation doesn't help that much, but if you read through the comments on the Wordpress plugin page you'll find good answers.In short, figure out which plugins _don't_ need to be loaded on every page in the **Global Plugins** menu item; just drag them to the right column. Next, re-add these globally disabled plugins to specific pages or posts that need them. This is done either on the page or post itself (it will now have a new "Plugin Organizer" section), or using the **Plugin Filters** menu item.

Comment: (cont'd) On the Plugin Filters page (or individual page or post), do just the opposite: Drag the plugin from the right column to the left, enabling it. For the filter, use the permalink to the page.

It's easy to create a filter, also, for admin-only plugins; just create one with the "yoursite/admin" permalink. Then, disable them globally and re-enable them in the filter's settings.

**A word of caution:** If you disable the wrong plugins globally you might break your site. Never done this myself, but that's the warning I've seen and it makes sense. It can be fixed of course.